# Upload a full directory to IPFS using ipfs (js-ipfs-http-client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs

I want to upload a directory to ipfs on my browser using (js-ipfs-http-client) module.

I found this old issue. 
https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/issues/277
So I decided to use recursive  way to add files and get only one hash for it.

```
ipfs.addFromFs('path', { recursive: true, ignore: ['subfolder/to/ignore/**'] }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) { throw err }
            console.log(result)
        })
```

But it gave me this error. [fs Add doesn't work on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa6nv.png)

I need to upload a directory to ipfs using javascript but all resources I had found upload only one file.Or a lot of files with array of hashes. I need a way to upload all files of directory and get the with only one hash. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yehia, I believe the answer you are looking for is at https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-http-client/blob/master/examples/upload-file-via-browser/src/App.js#L29-L67

```
// Example #1
// Add file to IPFS and return a CID
saveToIpfs (files) {
  let ipfsId
  this.ipfs.add([...files], { progress: (prog) => console.log(`received: ${prog}`) })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      ipfsId = response[0].hash
      console.log(ipfsId)
      this.setState({ added_file_hash: ipfsId })
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}

// Example #2
// Add file to IPFS and wrap it in a directory to keep the original filename
saveToIpfsWithFilename (files) {
  const file = [...files][0]
  let ipfsId
  const fileDetails = {
    path: file.name,
    content: file
  }
  const options = {
    wrapWithDirectory: true,
    progress: (prog) => console.log(`received: ${prog}`)
  }
  this.ipfs.add(fileDetails, options)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      // CID of wrapping directory is returned last
      ipfsId = response[response.length - 1].hash
      console.log(ipfsId)
      this.setState({ added_file_hash: ipfsId })
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: better to copy code to answer, github content may change later

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using the `addAll` [method](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#ipfsaddallsource-options).

Here is the rough example :

```
  const addedFiles: AddedFiles[] = []
  for await (const file of ipfsClient.addAll(
    globSource(path, '**/*', {
      hidden: true,
    }),
    { ...ipfsOptions, fileImportConcurrency: 50 }
  )) {
    addedFiles.push({
      cid: file.cid.toString(),
      path: file.path,
      size: file.size,
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, bro this is exactly what I needed.